# Prevent ItemChecked event on a ListView from interfering with SubItemClicked using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, listview, checkbox

I am using a [in-place editable listview](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ListViewCellEditors.aspx) control for a project.

The editable listview adds a 'SubItemClicked' event so that each 'cell' can be edited.

```
lstSD2.SubItemClicked += new ListViewEx.SubItemEventHandler(lstSD2_SubItemClicked);
```

I also have the listview checkboxes enabled with a 'ItemChecked' event.

The problem is that once the 'ItemChecked' event is enabled double-clicking on any row fires the 'ItemChecked' event and prevents the 'SubItemClicked' event from firing.

Is there a way to enforce the need to actually 'check' the listview checkbox instead of firing whenever the row is double-clicked?

One possible solution is to disable the listview's 'DoubleClickActivation':

```
this.lstShuntData2.DoubleClickActivation = false;
```

The main drawback to this is that the users may find the listview a little too sensitive to any mouseclick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET specifically adds this functionality to a ListView. Don't ask me why.

To get rid of it, listen for `NM_DBLCLK` reflected notification, and in the handler for that do this::

```
NativeMethods.NMHDR nmhdr = (NativeMethods.NMHDR)m.GetLParam(typeof(NativeMethods.NMHDR));

switch (nmhdr.code) {
case NM_DBLCLK:
    // The default behavior of a .NET ListView with checkboxes is to toggle the checkbox on
    // double-click. That's just silly, if you ask me :)
    if (this.CheckBoxes) {
        // How do we make ListView not do that silliness? We could just ignore the message
        // but the last part of the base code sets up state information, and without that
        // state, the ListView doesn't trigger MouseDoubleClick events. So we fake a
        // right button double click event, which sets up the same state, but without
        // toggling the checkbox.
        nmhdr.code = NM_RDBLCLK;
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(nmhdr, m.LParam, false);
    }
    break;
```

This is one of the many problems that [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) solves for you. Even if you don't use the whole project, you can look at the source code and figure out how to do things yourself.