# How to handle Windows Messages

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, windows-messages

I'm trying to prevent a checkbox inside a ListView to get checked on a double click event.

I already did:

```
listView.SelectedItems[0].Checked = (listView.SelectedItems[0].Checked) ? false : true;
```

But the checked event get called and the checkmark blinks inside the square box so I really think it sucks hard time.

I stumbled upon this answer:
[Prevent ItemChecked event on a ListView from interfering with SubItemClicked using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065183/c-prevent-itemchecked-event-on-a-listview-from-interering-with-subitemclicked/3074625#3074625)

It seems to be the perfect way to do so, but I don't know how to make this work. I tried to read a bit about notifications, messages, etc but found nothing understable enough for me to apply it to my code.

Could someone shed me some light on this please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Simply implement the ItemCheck event.  You can cancel the check by changing the e.NewValue property.  A silly example:

```
    private void listView1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
        // Disable checking odd numbered items
        if (e.Index % 2 == 1) {
            e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I can't seem to find any ItemCheck event in my ListView's events?! :-/

Comment: Even if I wasn't finding it, I decided to add myself the event to my designer.cs file (this.listView.ItemCheck += new System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventHandler(this.listView_ItemCheck);)

Comment: Your code is not preventing the check from doubleclick to happen :-/ I'll try to work something out from this event.

Comment: It's not preventing the checkbox to get checked on double-click for me :-/ It is still getting checked. I don't know if it has something to do with this but FYI I have the double click event as well.

Comment: I can't help you with these mysterious problems if you only give me a 'it doesn't work' diagnostic.  Let's focus on the missing ItemCheck event.  What version of VS, what version of .NET, what version of Windows?  Post a small repro project on a file sharing service.

Comment: I'm using VS2010 SP1 (v10.0.40219.1), working with .NET v4.0.30319 on Windows 7 64bits SP1. Here's the source on my github repo https://github.com/tbergeron/todoTxt/blob/master/MainForm.cs Thanks!

Comment: The ItemCheck event is on line 136 and the DoubleClick event is on line 123.